# how do I get css styles using simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to get content from another website. I have tried this below coding.

```
<?php
    require_once("simple_html_dom.php");

    $webpage = file_get_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php');
    $gettxt = $webpage->find("div#answer-9813422",0)->innertext;
    echo $gettxt;

?>
```

It prints the HTML results correctly without css styles. But, I have to show the css styles also. How do I get the appropriate css selectors of these HTML section?

[image]

Comment: You are scraping html and getting html. You won't get the CSS styles this way. One option is to include all CSS files from stackoverflow in your page but that would mess up your page CSS also

Comment: Do you mean the html? Just leave off `->innertext`