# How can I read an html page and convert its content to xml to read the content?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, parsing, html-parsing

I have a link to html page - a blog page - and I want to read its content from php laravel code and extract some data fields from there.

The pages would be like this one:
https://www.mashvisor.com/blog/san-francisco-real-estate-market-worth-it/

I'm using Laravel 5.0 to do so. How could I extract fields like author and titles?

Comment: This is a very broad question, I think you should do some more initial research.

Comment: I would indeed start looking more into DOM crawlers. Laravel will not help you with this. I have personally used tools like the symfony dom crawler for this. Good luck.

Comment: You could start taking a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php or even better here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents

Answer (score 1):

Since the site you are wanting to get data from is Wordpress just use the available api. It provides the data you're looking for in json format.

https://www.mashvisor.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts