# How can I scrape the values from the source code of a particular url with PHP?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

Inside the source code of the url I want to **scrape** I can see this:

> ```
> <div class="price">
> 22.96€
> </div>
> ```

And this is the php file that I created but it´s not returning any value:

> ```
> <?php
>   $data_scraped = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/es/busquedas/?type%5B%5D=steam&query=motogp+20');
>   $the_start = explode('<div class="price">',$data_scraped);
>   
>   $the_end = explode('</div>',$the_start[1]);
>   
>   echo $the_end[0];
> ?>
> ```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php) one which makes use of [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for web scraping in PHP.

Restructuring your code for usage with simple_html_dom:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com/es/busquedas/?type%5B%5D=steam&query=motogp+20');
$price = $html->find('div[class=price]');

echo $price->plaintext."<br>";
?>
```