# php files list with metatags

Tags: php, meta-tags

I wonder if it could be possible, with php, list and link all php files of a (website) folder *with their metatags* (author, description, keywords and so on).

List and link all the php files in a folder is **easy** (with glob), but so far I didn't manage to add their **metatags** (from php variables).
The following code works, and I can get meta-tags from php variables of a not yet processed php file (such as $author="some name"), but it show only a *single file* metatags:

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://path-to-a-folder/name-of-a-file');
echo $tags['author'];    
echo $tags['keywords'];  
echo $tags['description']; 
?>
```

(If I don't add the name of a file, I get metatags of the folder's index file)

My question is: there is a way to get the metatags of **all** the php files of a folder?
It would be useful for a webmaster, with a website folder frequently updated.

EDIT

If someone is interested I have found a solution (I was given one) [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/list-and-link-php-files-in-a-folder-and-its-metatag-description/368341/84).
Maybe the code is redundant, but it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php glob - scan in subfolders for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160696/php-glob-scan-in-subfolders-for-a-file). Also [Web scraping in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php).

Comment: Unfortunately no: list and link php files is quite easy, the problem is get their meta-tags. I search for a website solution for folders frequently updated: it would be useful have a description and other meta-tags at the side of the file names.

Comment: The second link you provided seems about _html_ metatags, while I speak of metatags as _php_ variables inside a php file not yet processed.

Comment: use the ``glob`` function to read all the files in a directory and then loop through the data returned and fetch the meta tags for each file.

Comment: There is no method or function which will read meta tags of files within a directory specified.

Comment: I don't think so: in this thread I managed to get description and title: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/list-and-link-php-files-in-a-folder-and-its-metatag-description/368341/78.  

The problem is _author_ metatag, that is shown as a _digit_ and not as text.