# Html, Get the attribute data without using id and class name of div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask if its possible to get such value:

Here is the sample div

```
<div class="" data-target-id="VALUE" data-id="legacy"></div>
```

In sample div, lets say I want to get the value of the attribute 'data-target-id'.

Is it possible using domhtml?

Comment: Where will you use this value? Can you use javascript to get this value?

Comment: @Bunny Hi! sorry for the late reply, lets say i just want to get it for some basic automation, if it possible to get the value using js, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of a data attribute in JavaScript, you must use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

To select only the **first** div in DOM having a `data-target-id` attribute and print its value :

```js
const targetId = document.querySelector('[data-target-id]');
console.log(targetId.dataset.targetId); //VALUE
```

If there are more than 1 div having having a `data-target-id` attribute, you can use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` then use a loop to print the targetIds.

If you want to select only div with a `data-id="legacy"`, you can use this:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id="legacy"]'); //get all div with a data-id="legacy"
divs.forEach(div => {
  console.log(div.dataset.targetId); //output corresponding target-id
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir!, can i apply this on DomHTML?

Comment: If you have an html file with a `script` tag pointing to a javascript file containing my code, then yes. You can also execute my code directly in the developer console.

Comment: the html file will be coming from a different website url, and I want to get the value of data-target-id attribute to log it on console.

Comment: In that case, go directly to the website and open [Dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/) (F12 or CTRL + SHIFT + I). Go to the `console` panel and paste my code. Press Enter.

Comment: Hi! sorry for my late reply, but what i want is use domhtml to my php code to get the html file of a website and do some basic task using the value that I will get to the said attribute and use it somewhere else.

Comment: What you described is web scraping. I'm not familiar with PHP but I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php) which might help you. There are also external libraries which can simplify web scraping.